# server returns java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL

Tags: java, http, bad-request

I am trying to call rest API which is documented like this

```
curl -X POST "https://url/api/v1/className/doSomething" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer token" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d
```

Here is my code sends http post. It works good with all http apis I used before but not for this.

```
        String result = "";

        RequestProcess process = LogManager.getInstance().newProcess();
        process.setProcessName(url);
        process.setRequestContent(requestContent);

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().registerModule(new Jdk8Module()).registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());


        String rawData = mapper.writeValueAsString(requestContent);

        String charset = "UTF-8";
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)new URL(url).openConnection();
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=" + charset);
        connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

        try (OutputStream output = connection.getOutputStream()) {
            output.write(rawData.getBytes(charset));
        }

        InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
        result = StreamUtil.toString(inputStream);

        process.setResponseContent(result);
        LogManager.getInstance().endProcess(process);

        return result;
```

I am getting an error

**java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: url**

I tried to do the same from postman and it works. Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like your url variable is not initialize properly. You are not using curl request properly. There is no data posted in the request. So with null payload passed, expected exception is 400 only

Answer (score 0):

What do you send as Data? at least you should send -d {} for empty data or remove -d

Comment: I am sending json "{name: value}"

Comment: can you provide the method signature, and also use for instance this formatter to check your json data : https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: curl -d '{"name":"value"}' -H "accept: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer token" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST https://url/api/v1/className/doSomething

Answer (score 0):

If it is running in POSTMAN, you can get the corresponding `curl`
 request from it. By clicking on `Code` and select `cURL` from available options.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it by removing **charset** in the **Content-Type** section.
After modification this line looks like this

```
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
```